# How can i parse specific string using indexof and substring?

Tags: c#, .net

```
int firstTag = source.IndexOf("data-token=");
int lastTag = source.IndexOf("\"href", firstTag);
int startIndex = firstTag + 12;
int endIndex = lastTag + 5;
string authenticityToken = source.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```

The string I want to parse is from here:

```
<a class="bizLink" data-token="-iUzEhgdscgbpj5VMi5zoh54FTeFt8M4mj5nsiodxR5VzZOhniodpj6nFQg0nce3MhUxFSgdxjM4J
jUVzZuNu8o0sREnFSUzISUXzZWh4iodGQfdxR5VzZWh4iodGQfhli6fnce_=" 
                           href="
```

I want to get only the string between " and " only this:

```
-iUzEhgdscgbpj5VMi5zoh54FTeFt8M4mj5nsiodxR5VzZOhniodpj6nFQg0nce3MhUxFSgdxjM4J
    jUVzZuNu8o0sREnFSUzISUXzZWh4iodGQfdxR5VzZWh4iodGQfhli6fnce_=
```

But what I get with my code is this long string I wanted, but also all the rest of the file text.

Comment: [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Why is this tagged *winforms*?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper you never parsed html content in winforms?

Comment: @L.B: Following that logic, I suggest the tags *computer*, *earth*, *desk* and *human* be added.

Comment: It seems that you just need to remove the +5 in the calc used for endindex. This is easy to test. Why don't you use a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working example http://ideone.com/U224iZ

```
string start = "data-token=";
  string end = " href";

  string source = "<a class='bizLink' data-token='-iUzEhgdscgbpj5VMi5zoh54FTeFt8M4mj5nsiodxR5VzZOhniodpj6nFQg0nce3MhUxFSgdxjM4JjUVzZuNu8o0sREnFSUzISUXzZWh4iodGQfdxR5VzZWh4iodGQfhli6fnce_=1\" href='";

  int firstTag = source.IndexOf(start);
  int lastTag = source.IndexOf(end, firstTag );
  int startIndex = firstTag + start.Length +1;
  int endIndex = lastTag;
  string authenticityToken = source.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex -1);
  Console.Write(authenticityToken);
  Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 4):

The sane way would be to use a HTML parser and querying library. I can suggest [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery/), which is a jQuery-like library in .NET. You could use a selector like `a[data-token]` to match your anchor, then extract the attribute value.

This is the correct way of doing things.

---

But if you **only** ever want to get this one attribute and don't do anything with the HTML source ever again, it *might* be easier to just use a regex, but beware: [parsing HTML with regex is evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

So if all you want to do is just extract this one piece of information, as an exceptional measure, for your information, you could use that:

```
var m = Regex.Match(source, @"data-token\s*=\s*""(?<token>.+?)""");
var authenticityToken = m.Groups["token"].Value;
```

But try CsQuery first. It's a **much** better approach.

Comment: I agree, just think that the regular expression pattern can be simpler: "data-token=\"([^\"]+)\""

Comment: While this is true, I opted for a more correct pattern (html allows spaces around the `=` sign). Besides, I like to use named captures, it makes the regex easier to read IMO.